# wp_editor() usage in custom meta box

Tags: theme-development, custom-field, metabox

i am building a custom meta box having a classic editor input rather than just input. The reason for using wp_editor is that I wanted to add paragraphs of text inside div but the simple input escaped the html. Now i am using this function.
Now the problem is that when I output the data of this editor input, it escapes html.
Here is the code I use for output.

echo get_post_meta($post_id, 'skyscraper_post', true );

I use this code for adding meta boxes.

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes_post', function ( $post ) {
    if ( $post->_wp_page_template === 'page-templates/skyscraper-post.php' ) {
        add_meta_box( 'sky_post_excerpt', 'SkyScraper Post Excerpt and Links', 'sky_post_excerpts', 'post', 'advanced', 'high' );
    }
});
function sky_post_excerpts() {
     global $post;
    $values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
    $data = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'skyscraper_post', true);


    $strong_title = isset( $values['skyscraper_strong'] ) ? esc_html( $values['skyscraper_strong'][0] ) : "";
    $title = isset( $values['skyscraper_post_title'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['skyscraper_post_title'][0] ) : "";
    $text = isset( $values['skyscraper_post'] ) ?  $values['skyscraper_post'][0]  : "";
    $image = isset( $values['skyscraper_post_image'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['skyscraper_post_image'][0] ) : "";

    // We'll use this nonce field later on when saving.
    wp_nonce_field( 'my_post_meta_box_nonce', 'post_meta_box_nonce' );
    ?>

    <table class="form-table">
        <tbody>
        <tr valign="top">
            <th scope="row">
                <label><strong>Skyscraper Title</strong></label>
            </th>
            <td>
                <p><input class="widefat" name="skyscraper_strong" id="skyscraper_strong" ><?php echo $strong_title; ?></input>
                </p>
                <p><input class="widefat" rows="4" name="skyscraper_post_title" id="skyscraper_post_title" value="<?php echo $title; ?>"/>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr valign="top">
            <th scope="row">
                <label for="skyscraper_post"><strong>Skyscraper Page Excerpt</strong></label>
            </th>
            <td>
                <?php wp_editor( $data, 'post_meta_box', $settings = array('textarea_name'=>'skyscraper_post')); ?>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="top">
            <th scope="row">
                <label for="skyscraper_image"><strong>SVG Image Link</strong></label>
            </th>
            <td>
                <p><input class="widefat" rows="4" name="skyscraper_post_image" id="skyscraper_post_image" value="<?php echo $image; ?>"/>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
    <?php
}
```

To save the data I use this code.

```
    add_action( 'save_post', 'post_meta_box_save' );
    function post_meta_box_save( $post_id ) {
   // Bail if we're doing an auto save
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

    // if our nonce isn't there, or we can't verify it, bail
    if( !isset( $_POST['post_meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['post_meta_box_nonce'], 'my_post_meta_box_nonce' ) ) return;

    // if our current user can't edit this post, bail
    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;
    //$allowed = wp_kses_allowed_html();
    $allowed= array(
        'p' => array(
            'class' => array(),
            'id' => array(),
        ),
        'strong' => array(),
    );


    // Make sure your data is set before trying to save it
    if( isset( $_POST['skyscraper_post'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'skyscraper_post', wp_kses( $_POST['skyscraper_post'], $allowed ) );

    // Make sure your data is set before trying to save it
    if( isset( $_POST['skyscraper_post_image'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'skyscraper_post_image', wp_kses( $_POST['skyscraper_post_image'], $allowed ) );

    // Make sure your data is set before trying to save it
    if( isset( $_POST['skyscraper_strong'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'skyscraper_strong', wp_kses( $_POST['skyscraper_strong'], $allowed ) );

    // Make sure your data is set before trying to save it
    if( isset( $_POST['skyscraper_post_title'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'skyscraper_post_title', wp_kses( 

    $_POST['skyscraper_post_title'], $allowed ) );
    }
```

I don't know why the html is being escaped.
Any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

here is the escaped output.
[image]

Comment: This part escapes the HTML code: `htmlspecialchars($_POST['skyscraper_post'])`. Perhaps you could just remove that and the `htmlspecialchars_decode()` ?

Comment: after removing this it still escapes the html. Any other way to output the data

Comment: Have you tried to decode it using `wp_specialchars_decode` instead of `htmlspecialchars_decode`? Also you could use the `sanitize_text_field` instead of `wp_kses` to sanitize the $_POST data.

Comment: applied the methods but still escaping p tags.

Comment: is there any other way to output data of wp_editor other than get post meta

Comment: Try `wp_kses_data( $_POST['skyscraper_post'] )` or `wp_kses_post( $_POST['skyscraper_post'] )`.

Comment: "other than get post meta"? What exactly do you mean? If you saved the data to the post meta table, then `get_post_meta()` would be the preferred way of getting the saved value. And `update_post_meta( 123, 'skyscraper_post', wp_kses_data( $_POST['skyscraper_post'] ) )` worked well in my case - when I retrieved the metadata, the HTML is not escaped in the TinyMCE/classic editor. `wp_kses( $_POST['skyscraper_post'], $GLOBALS['allowedtags'] )` worked, too.

Comment: why in my case it is being escaped. let me add an screenshot of escaped html.

Comment: What a tiny screenshot there... but is that *in* the classic editor, "Visual" mode?

Comment: no but on frontend.

Comment: Well, take a look at my answer. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may not solve the problem, but I hope it helps you.

1. In the `sky_post_excerpts()` function, I used this to display the TinyMCE/classic editor: (the `$data` is `get_post_meta($post->ID, 'skyscraper_post', true)`)

   ```
   <?php wp_editor( $data, 'post_meta_box', array('textarea_name'=>'skyscraper_post')); ?>
   ```
2. In the `post_meta_box_save()` function, I saved the meta like so, where `$allowed` is `wp_kses_allowed_html()`:

   ```
   update_post_meta( $post_id, 'skyscraper_post', wp_kses( $_POST['skyscraper_post'], $allowed ) );
   ```
3. On the front-end, I display the metadata like so:

   ```
   // This is really just an example. And I was on a single post.
   echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'skyscraper_post', true );
   ```

And everything worked well for me — all HTML remained as generated by the TinyMCE editor.

### UPDATE

> if I use visual not text in TinyMCE then the p tags doesn't show

`wp_kses_allowed_html()` when called without specifying the [`$context` parameter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses_allowed_html/#parameters), will use the global variable [`$allowedtags`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.1.1/src/wp-includes/kses.php#L412) which is an array of KSES allowed HTML elements, which (by default) do **not** include `p` tags/elements.

If you want to allow `p` elements, you can:

- Use `wp_kses_allowed_html( 'post' )` which will use the global variable [`$allowedposttags`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.1.1/src/wp-includes/kses.php#L53) which also holds similar array as the `$allowedtags` variable, but `$allowedposttags` has many elements allowed including `table` and `video`.
- Or manually enable the `p` elements:

  ```php
  $allowed = wp_kses_allowed_html();
  $allowed['p'] = array(); // allows all attributes!
  ```
- Same as above, but build your own allowed tags:

  ```php
  $allowed = array();
  $allowed['p'] = array(); // allows all attributes!
  ```

But, you shouldn't allow all attributes.. so:

```php
$allowed['p'] = array(
  'class' => true,
  'id'    => true,
  ...other attributes...
);
```

Comment: i got it but if I use visual not text in TinyMCE then the p tags doesn't show.

Comment: let me update my code.

Comment: I've just seen your question's edit. So are the `p` tags still being escaped? And I've also updated my answer - you already know some, but the update might still help you. Let me know.

Comment: it helped. also i just used wp_kses_post() instead. However, thanks for your help, i learned a lot from you. again,thanks.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. :)